# loading text file using cakephp + jquery.ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have the following (working) code for loading and parsing text files:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       var parse_file = function(url) {
           var ret = null;
           $.ajax({
               async: false,
               url: url,
               dataType: "text",
               success: function(data) {
                   // parse 'data' and set 'ret' 
               }
           });
           return ret;
       };

       var file_url = "./file.txt";
       var ret = parse_file(file_url);

       // ...
   });
```

However, if I put it into a cakephp's view file, it doesn't work anymore.
`data` contains a html-file with a cakephp error, that there is an undefined index.

Comment: what is the location of "./file.txt" file? if you simply give "/file.txt" as url, it will check for a file named 'file.txt' in webroot of you application and returns error if not found.

Comment: yes, i know, the file is in webroot and it exists

Comment: give full url instead of relative url and check if it is working

Comment: @nithin, sorry I didn't read your first comment carefully, it works, thank you !